# SSIS connection string error: ..."must consist of one or more components of the form X=Y, separated by semicolons...." .

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I am getting this error in my SSIS environment.

I have a package that imports a CSV file into a staging table.  In my efforts to find out what is causing the error - I have disable every step (one-by-one) in the package.  So now my output log looks like this:

SSIS package "C:***\Stage - Load Monthly Statistics CSV.dtsx" starting.

Information: 0x40016042 at Stage - Load Monthly Statistics CSV: The package is attempting to configure from the parent variable "User::BatchID".

Warning: 0x8001201A at Stage - Load Monthly Statistics CSV: Configuration from a parent variable "User::BatchID" did not occur because there was no parent variable collection.

Error: 0xC0024108 at Stage - Load Monthly Statistics CSV: The connection string format is not valid. It must consist of one or more components of the form X=Y, separated by semicolons. This error occurs when a connection string with zero components is set on database connection manager.

Error: 0xC0024108 at Stage - Load Monthly Statistics CSV: The connection string format is not valid. It must consist of one or more components of the form X=Y, separated by semicolons. This error occurs when a connection string with zero components is set on database connection manager.

SSIS package "C:***\Stage - Load Monthly Statistics CSV.dtsx" finished: Success.

There are 5 connection strings in the project, 2 OLEDB ones to my SQLServer 2014 databases, 1 ADO.NET one to SQLServer 2014 and 2 FlatFile connections to import .CSV files.  The SQL Server ones are currently setup to use Windows auth (while I am troubleshooting) - but in production will use a SQL user and the password is a project parameter,

I have deleted and re-created each of the connections once already with no luck.  When the steps are enabled - the job completes all the steps (stages the csv data into SQL) successfully, but ends with an error because of these connection string errors.  I can't even tell which connection string is the problem.

Comment: Which of your connection strings doesn't consist of one or more components of the form X=Y, separated by semicolons?

Comment: `Configuration from a parent variable` + `This error occurs when a connection string with zero components is set on database connection manager` This smells strongly like something (parameter or configuration) is not being set. An expression is then wiping out your connection strings for a given thing. But, when all we have is error messages, it's hard to tell. Try setting the `DelayValidation` to True on your errorring connection managers

Answer (score -2):

I have solved the issue when I just run the task so the variable gets a value, can use a sequence container.
The error means that the variable has no value.

GL